# Python: how to index in a dataframe (panda) consisting of arrays and NaN

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, indexing, nan

I have a 16x10 panda dataframe with arrays and NaN values inside. My goal is to get the first index of each array with python. Currently I try to achieve this by using

`df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])`

but due to the NaN in my dataframe I get the following error:

`TypeError: ("'float' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index -2.0')`

Any idea how to index in my dataframe? [My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MADcN.png)

Comment: Something like df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if x else 0)

Comment: Hey Brennan, thanks for your commend! Your idea throws another error: `ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index -2.0')`

Comment: Using if conditions however was a nice idea: `df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if not np.isnan(x).any() else 0)` works fine! However, I'm going to compute mean values over columns in the next step. So instead of 0 I'd like to insert NaN again. How would I do that?

Comment: Oh nice :) you should write the answer your question.

Comment: instead of 0 use np.NaN

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton! I will.

Comment: Or maybe `df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if x != np.NaN else np.NaN)`

Comment: Prettier indeed, but throws `ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index -2.0')` again. If you know how to put any() in there it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if not np.isnan(x).any() else np.NAN)`

will do the job.